# How to create a service to start my mariadb?

Tags: windows, mariadb

I installed mysql and mariadb in the same pc(win10).Port 3306 binded with mysql, 3307 with mariadb.

```
net start mysql   #start  mysql server.
```

Start mariadb server.

```
F:/mariadb-10.3\bin\mysqld   --defaults-file=F:/mariadb-10.3\mysql\my.ini  --user=root
```

Start it in background.

```
start /B  F:/mariadb-10.3\bin\mysqld   --defaults-file=F:/mariadb-10.3\mysql\my.ini  --user=root
```

Now i want to create a service such as `net start mysql`

```
net start mariadb
```

How to make it in windows10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `sc` command from a command prompt to add MariaDB to services.

```
sc create MariaDB binpath= "F:/mariadb-10.3/bin/mysqld --defaults-file=F:/mariadb-10.3/mysql/my.ini" DisplayName= "MariaDB" start= "auto"
```

You probably don't need the `--user=root` in the command when running it as a service. It's usually not needed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run regedit. Export `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MySQL` hive into .REG file.
2. Edit this .REG file:

   - Replace all occurences of `mysql` with `mariadb`;
   - Edit ImagePath, set it to correct value (shown in your question as "Start mariadb server.").
3. Import the result of your edition back into registry.
4. Reboot (not nesessary but safe).

Answer (score 0):

please look https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_install_dbexe/ it very easy, just open your CMD as Administrator and type :

```
mysql_install_db.exe --datadir=F:/mariadb-10.3/bin/mysqld  --service=MariaDB --password=secret
```